# $12$ similar balls into $10$ different cells, where each cell will have even number of balls

Tags: combinatorics

We have $12$ similar balls we arrange them in $10$ distinct cells.

In how many arrangements will every cell have an even amount of balls (including $0$)?

---

I thought to use the formula:

$$
\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}
$$

And to look as if the balls come in pairs.

Namely, arrange $6$ pairs of balls in $10$ different cells.

Therefore, I get:

$$
\binom{6+10-1}{10-1} = \binom{15}{9}
$$

which is not the answer.

Can someone tell me why my thinking is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the given answer? I think your answer should be correct.

Comment: @vishnuKadiri The possible answers are (this is a question in my homeworks): $a.\binom{15}{6}2^6 \ b. \frac{12!}{2^6} \cdot 10^6, \ c. \binom{15}{6}, \ d. \binom{12}{6} \cdot 6! \cdot 10^6$ None of them fit $\binom{15}{9}$, correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: Why not? The answer is clearly C. Since $\ \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$

Comment: Right, my fault, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Community wiki post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) so that the question can be marked as closed.

As Vishnu Kadiri indicated in the comments, your answer is correct.  As Vishnu also indicated in the comments, since
$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n - k}$$
your answer $\binom{15}{9}$ is equal to the stated answer $\binom{15}{6}$ because
$$\binom{15}{9} = \binom{15}{15 - 9} = \binom{15}{6}$$